# Objective - C UIScrollView not working horizontally

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, xib

i read all the other replies for similar question but my project still don't work.
Any help?

This is my project.

----------------> viewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroll;
IBOutlet UIImageView *imagev;
}
```

----------------> viewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
imagev.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ka.jpg"];
[scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(700, 700)];
[scroll setScrollEnabled:TRUE];
[scroll setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:YES];
[scroll setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:YES];
}

@end
```

everything looks fine but the scrollview won't scroll..

EDIT: as they suggested here, the problem was Autolayout. with that i fixed the scrollview

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748326/uiscrollview-not-scrolling-horizontally

Comment: Is your UIScrollView scrolling vertically?

Comment: what is scrollview frame ?

Comment: How big is the scrollView? What exactly doesn't Work?

Comment: Check if the scrollView is connected from your nib file to the outlet in your controller.

Comment: i would LOVE to know why the heck i got -2 reputations just for asking this... i CLEARLY said i read the other questions but my projects wasnt still working...

Comment: i used a xib to build this... i was wanting to post an image but can't cause i need higher reputation. the scrollview is a small square about 200x200 and there is a bigger image. it only scroll vertically but not horizontally

Comment: please upload image in other site and give that URL

Comment: http://i39.tinypic.com/f52kva.png

Comment: please show the connections inspector (last tab in the panel on the right-hand side of Xcode interface builder). Select the scrollview and show the connections inspector, this way we can see if the scrollview is connected to your IBOutlet in the code.

Comment: http://i39.tinypic.com/2dinm87.png

Comment: To answer your previous question, the probable reason that you were downvoted was because you say "my project don't work". It is not those words that got the negative reviews, but the fact that you say nothing else at all, but just spit your code at us. You need to make sure that you note down what exactly you have tried and what EXACTLY doesn't work, and also give more detailed explanation of your app environment. You know what your app looks like, but we have no idea. Think with the fact that you are talking to strangers who don't know your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe Autolayout is causing the problem. Try turning it off.

1. Select the ViewController in the Storyboard or NIB
2. Click the 'File Inspector' tab on the right hand side of your Xcode window
3. Under the 'Interface Builder Document' section, uncheck 'Use Autolayout'

Comment: Autolayout is Apple's way to make supporting multiple screen sizes/resolutions easier (iPhone 4, iPhone 5 etc.). While it's supposed to make things easier, sometimes it gets in the way and causes unanticipated things to happen.

Comment: Removing auto-layout would mess with your screen if it were designed based on auto-layout in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

I've got a fix for you, and you can continue to use autolayout.

Implement the following method in "ViewController.m"

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(700, 700)];
}
```

And you can remove `[scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(700, 700)];` from the `-viewDidLoad` method.

This will fix it for you, and you can continue to use auto-layout. Auto-layout is a bit dodgy in iOS 6. But it is apparently much better in iOS 7.

Answer (score 1):

**Objective - C**
you can use this lines of code into your *.m file's - (void)viewDidLoad{} function:

```
[scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 800)];
[scroll setScrollEnabled:TRUE];
[scroll setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
[scroll setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:YES];
```

for this you need to take an IBOutlet property of UIScrollView into your *.h file this way:

```
IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroll;
```

And connect this from Storyboard.

Or,

You can use this method into your *.m file:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews { 
[scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, self.view.frame.size.height* 1.5)]; 
// this will pick height automatically from device's height and multiply it with 1.5
}
```

This both solution works for me in xcode-5, xcode-6, xcode-6.1, xcode-6.2

**Swift:**
You can use this swift code for similar type of issue:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:10, height:10)
}
```

Comment: The question was asked in 2013 and you're answering now? :| There's also an accepted...

Comment: @Lord: I'm also faced same problem last week. That's why I added not only Obj-C but also Swift fix up.

Comment: old questions can be answered as well.